# Different css image path for dev & prod

Tags: angular

I'm using angular and scss in an app and I need a different path for dev and prod. Using a different scss file

background-image: url($imgPath + 'assets/map.png');

basically my $imgPath variable has the value of '/' for dev and all works fine but for pro I don't ant the forward slash, so it is set to '' (empty). The problem is that when I build the app for prod with 'ng build --prod' it throws an error saying it can't resolve the png files.

```
ERROR in Child compilation failed:
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: D:\ClientApp\src\app\components\board\board.
component.scss:8:26: Can't resolve 'map.png' in 'D:\ClientApp\src\app\components\board'

NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: D:\ClientApp\src\app\components\board\board.component.scss:8:26: Can't resolve 'map.png' in 'D:\ClientApp\src\app\components\board'

   6 |   align-items: center;
   7 |   width: auto;
>  8 |   background-image: url("assets/map.png");
     |                          ^
   9 |   background-position: center;
  10 |   background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

It seems that I have the output wrong and it won't work but it's not. I am hosting the app in a 3rd party environment and the '/' is causing a wrong path in that environment. 
Not sure if I am using the best solution by replacing the scss file in the angular configuration file but seems to work, the issue is that the build fails because in complains about the wrong path that is not wrong for what I want.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a different css file for each environment.
Look my files

angular.json:

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"projects": {
  "neo-assets-ngcli": {
    "root": "",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "projectType": "application",
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
          "outputPath": "build",
          "index": "src/index.html",
          "main": "src/main.ts",
          "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "namedChunks": true,
          "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
          "assets": [
            "src/assets/fonts",
            "src/assets/js/settings.js",
            "src/assets/img",
            "src/assets/.htaccess",
            "src/assets/index.tpl",
            "src/favicon.ico",
            "src/assets/csv",
            {
              "glob": "**/*",
              "input": "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images",
              "output": "assets/"
            }
          ],
          "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/environments/scss-dev"
              ]
          }
        },
        "configurations": {
          "production": {
            "optimization": true,
            "outputHashing": "all",
            "sourceMap": {
              "hidden": false,
              "scripts": true,
              "styles": true
            },
            "extractCss": true,
            "namedChunks": false,
            "aot": true,
            "extractLicenses": true,
            "vendorChunk": false,
            "buildOptimizer": true,
            "fileReplacements": [
              {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/environments/scss-prod"
              ]
          }
          }
        }
      },
      "test": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
        "options": {
          "main": "src/test.ts",
          "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
          "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
          "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",             
          "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/environments/scss-dev"
              ]
          }
        },

      },
      "lint": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
        "options": {
          "tsConfig": [
            "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
          ],
          "exclude": [
            "**/node_modules/**"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "neo-assets-ngcli-e2e": {
    "root": "e2e",
    "sourceRoot": "e2e",
    "projectType": "application",
    "architect": {
      "e2e": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
        "options": {
          "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
          "devServerTarget": "neo-assets-ngcli:serve"
        },
        "configurations": {
          "noserve": {
            "devServerTarget": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "lint": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
        "options": {
          "tsConfig": [
            "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
          ],
          "exclude": [
            "**/node_modules/**"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"defaultProject": "neo-assets-ngcli",
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "prefix": "",
    "styleext": "scss"
  },
  "@schematics/angular:directive": {
    "prefix": ""
  }
}
```

}

Look the includePaths attribute in each environment.

Then I have a globalVars.scss file in each folder. Each one with their path.

And finally, in the styles.scss the first line:

@import "globalVars";

Comment: That's my approach. The problem is that when building the solution for prod, the path is just 'assets/map.png' and it seems wrong, the build system can't find the file, and thus the build fails. Can I skip this validation?

Comment: That's why you have a different file for each environment. In my globalVars.scss file I have in development $my-base-path: '' and in prod: $my-base-path: '.' . Then I use that variable in each background url like this: background: url("#{$my-base-path}/assets/img/icons/Enhanced/id-card.svg");

Comment: I understand the different file approach and it 's what I'm doing. It generates a different output per environment. For prod it will generate url("assets/flag.png") and that's what I want, but the problem it that the build doesn't finish, it complains that this path is wrong (check the error I posted above). Do you know how to suppress this error?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the relative path the Angular build your images with webpack and you don't need a variable.

Example with relative path: `background-image: url("~/assets/map.png");`;

When you use the absolute path the Angular copy all assets folder, and you alsow don't need a variable.

Example with absolute path: `background-image: url("/assets/map.png");`

If your application is not in the root of your domain you must use [--deployUrl](https://angular.io/cli/build) command with `ng build`.

Comment: It makes sense but setting the "~/assets/map.png" the output will be "/assets/map.png". Why? I don't know the path of my app, it will be hosted on facebook with the following url https://apps-myAppNumber.apps.fbsbx.com/instant-bundle/some_number/other_number_changing_every_upload/main.js